# self organizing maps interpretation

Tags: visualization, self-organizing-maps, interpretation

I would like to know how do I interpret SOM output. for example

input

```
data = [1 100;
         1 100;
         1 100;
         1 100;
         55 55;
         ];
```

the output

```
http://s21.postimg.org/tqdcungjr/SOMM.jpg
```

can anyone tell me please ?

Comment: I can't see the output - it's blocked from here. Usually it gives you clusters...

Comment: Click on the link I could not insert the output pic because I have to have at least 10 reputations and i have only 6